# Improving performance of loop by using different list types

Tags: c#, list, performance, loops, dictionary

I have the following algorithm which works fine for smaller date ranges, however if I increase the date range to about a year (`startDate`, `endDate`) it obviously drops performance because I loop every minute of each day, is there a way to improve the performance by using different list types such as hashsets or dictionaries or are there other fallbacks I'm not aware of?

`listWorkTime` contains around 300+ entries where some date ranges could overlap or being the same but having different `TimeRangeId`

```
private List<DateSharedWork> CalculateDateSharedWork(DateTime startDate,
    DateTime endDate, ICollection<WorkTime> listWorkTime)
{
    List<DateSharedWork> listDateSharedWork = new List<DateSharedWork>();

    // +1 to include last day at full
    int range = endDate.Subtract(startDate).Days + 1;

    // start at startDate
    Parallel.For(0, range, i =>
    {
        DateTime currDate = startDate.AddDays(i);

        //set minute interval
        double everyNMinutes = 1.0;
        double minutesADay = 1440.0;

        // reset counter
        int work_counter = 0;
        int lowWork_counter = 0;
        int noWork_counter = 0;

        int l = (int)(minutesADay / everyNMinutes);

        for (int j = 0; j < l; j++)
        {
            DateTime check15 = currDate.AddMinutes(j * everyNMinutes);

            // check if listWorkTime includes current date
            var foundTime = listWorkTime
                .Where(x => check15 >= x.FromDate && check15 <= x.ToDate).ToList();

            if (foundTime.Count(x => x.TimeRangeId == 1) > 0)
            {
                // found interval that is within work hours
                work_counter++;
                noWork_counter++;
            }
            else
            {
                if (foundTime.Count(x => x.TimeRangeId == 2) > 0)
                {
                    // found intervall that is within low work hours
                    lowWork_counter++;
                    noWork_counter++;
                }
            }
        };

        double work = everyNMinutes / minutesADay * work_counter;
        double lowWork = everyNMinutes / minutesADay * lowWork_counter;
        double noWork = 1.0 - (everyNMinutes / minutesADay * noWork_counter);

        listDateSharedWork.Add(new DateSharedWork(currDate, work, lowWork, noWork));
    });

    listDateSharedWork.Sort((x, y) => DateTime.Compare(x.Date, y.Date));

    return listDateSharedWork;
}
```

**Edit***

class definitions

```
public class DateSharedWork
  {

    public DateSharedWork(DateTime date, double? work = 0.0, double? lowWork = 0.0, double? noWork = 1.0)
    {
      this.Date = date;
      this.Work = work.Value;
      this.LowWork = lowWork.Value;
      this.NoWork = noWork.Value;
    }

    public DateTime Date { get; private set; }
    public double Work { get; private set; }
    public double LowWork { get; private set; }
    public double NoWork { get; private set; }
  }
```

Comment: could you please post your `DateSharedWork` type as well?

Comment: As a side note be aware that the `List<T>` class is not thread-safe. Calling the `listDateSharedWork.Add` method from multiple threads in parallel may result to internal state corruption.

Comment: First of all **filter the input** list with `Where()`, then did you try to use `GroupBy()` to **group the input** like `.GroupBy(x => CalculateOffsetFromStartDate(x.Date))`? Done that you already know the number of items in the output list (pre-allocate) and simply go through each bucket. Also note that you can't hard-code things like `minutesADay` (time changes...)

Answer (score 0):

I would try to add a uint in DateSharedWork to store an integer as representation of the date

i.e. : 09-07-2021-10:05:12.13546 => 202109071005

You can add the calculation of this uint field in the DateSharedWork  constructor. It will surely cost at the loading of data.
Or you can tried to add the field and the calculation in the underlying DB and performing the calculation when performing upsert.

In the end i think it might improve query performance in your code. At least I already saw this approach in a Data Cube perf hint.

Answer (score 0):

You could speed up the calculation of the `foundTime` list, by limiting the search to only these `WorkTime` instances that are relevant with the `currDate`. To do this you must first build a `Dictionary` that has a `DateTime` as key, a `List<WorkTime>` as value:

```
Dictionary<DateTime, List<WorkTime>> perDay = new();
foreach (var workTime in listWorkTime)
{
    for (var d = workTime.FromDate.Date; d < workTime.ToDate.Date.AddDays(1); d.AddDays(1))
    {
        if (!perDay.TryGetValue(d, out var list)) perDay.Add(d, list = new());
        list.Add(workTime);
    }
}
```

This constitutes an extra work that must be done before starting the calculations, but hopefully it will speed the calculations enough to compensate for the initial cost.

Then you will be able to replace this:

```
var foundTime = listWorkTime
    .Where(x => check15 >= x.FromDate && check15 <= x.ToDate).ToList();
```

With this:

```
List<WorkTime> foundTime;
if (perDay.TryGetValue(currDate, out List<WorkTime> currDateList))
{
    foundTime = currDateList
        .Where(x => check15 >= x.FromDate && check15 <= x.ToDate)
        .ToList();
}
else
{
    foundTime = new();
}
```

I would also suggest to replace the `Parallel.For` loop with a normal `for` loop. The parallel programming has quite a lot of gotchas, ready to catch the unwary by surprise.